# Where to find this messageBlock Checkout/cart Magento

Tags: php, magento

I posted this question because I'm a bit lost, I've solved this once already this June and now it's back and I don't know why and what went wrong. I hope you could help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvmHj.png --- 
I've been trying to find the notice message in the yellow box? because something went wrong. because whenever I try to checkout without checking the box it proceeds to the one page checkout. and suppose to be it shouldn't only when the checkbox is checked, so I'm looking for the file that contains the notice message so I can modify it.

1. I've been looking in the following directories:

   - template/checkout/
   - core/Checkout/

but still the notice message is nowhere to be found.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the minimum order amount definitely set correctly in the backend? See [here](http://www.measureddesigns.com/design-blog/minimum-order-value-magento/) for info.

Comment: yes it's set, what I'm looking for is the source of the notice message because I'm lost looking for it. :(

Comment: I think Magento uses the `global_messages` block to render any success/failure messages on each page. Searching your codebase for the actual error HTML or string probably won't work, because they'll be set using `->addFailure` or `->addSuccess` or similar. 

Remember you can enable Template Path Hints to see exactly what template is rendering the message. [Here](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-).

Comment: the line of code that renders the message is this:
     echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
specifically looking for the notice message not this one. I've been at the cart.phtml a dozen times, even from it's controller and parentController.
I just need the location of the notice message just the content of the Yellow box that's all.

Comment: Looks like that comes from `code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php` ~line 215. It seems to be composing the messages using messy HTML. But like I said you won't find that specific message in there - it's probably set using a key (e.g. `total_error_msg`) which corresponds to a message in a database table or a locale CSV file. Inside the `foreach` loop in the function above you could probably `print_r($message->getData())` and see if it has any helpful info on the message source.

Comment: are you sure? because like I said I solved this once, I edited that notice message that's why it has a checkbox. but now that it rose from the forgotten xD I couldn't find it. :(

Comment: Ah, in that case, you should be able to use `grep` or some other file-search tool to search for distinctive bits of HTML like your checkbox's ID, name, label, whatever.